# stop horizontal scrolling on ckeditor to keep content inside editor window

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

i am facing a problem with my ckeditor.ckeditor content scroll in the x direction with the increasing amount of content.It causing me a design problem.
How can i make it stop? i want it in such a way that if content grow it will move down in the vertical direction only ,not in the horizontal direction.

[image]

Comment: Does the [demonstration of CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) give you what you want?

Comment: no ,you see if i press and hold any letter ,when the cursor reach the edge a horizontal scroll bar appeared.I want that the sentence will break and move to next line in such cases

Comment: I've [tested the demonstration page](https://i.imgur.com/GScB2wl.png) and it wraps the text in the editor (even without spaces). I'm sure that is what you want.

Comment: [Use the css word-wrap: break-word;](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Word-Wrap-Text-Box)

Comment: @magreenberg use it where?

Comment: found another issue...chrome is ok..but problem is in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your JS file

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = 'myckeditorcssfile.css';
```

Then put this inside that css file.

```
body
{
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: inside ckeditor file there is a css file  named 'content.css' .do i need to create this css file on my own or i put the css code inside that 'content.css'

Comment: put it in the content.css file at the end.

Comment: but there is already a body tag in that file and i used those css on the body tab.got no success

Comment: try adding !important after it. I would need to see your code.

Comment: found the issue...chrome is ok..but problem is in firefox

Comment: yea firefox 36 now supports white-space in textarea. add white-space:pre-wrap; to the body of the css file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99009/discussion-between-al-zami-and-magreenberg).